# How do I use Model in Helper - CakePHP 2.x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I recently upgraded my app from cake 1.3.x to cake 2.x. Now I have a helper which uses model in some function. Initially syntax for loading model was (working for 1.3.x)

```
     App::import('Model', $modelName);
     $modelObject = &ClassRegistry::getObject($modelName);    
     $modelObject->find()
```

Now I changed it to following

```
    App::uses($modelName,'Model');
    $modelObject = &ClassRegistry::getObject($modelName);
    $modelObject->find()
```

Problem is, this conversion is not working. Can anybody tell me where am I doing wrong. Thanking in advance.

PS: 
Error message is:
Call to a member function find() on a non-object

Comment: the correct syntax always was just `$User = ClassRegistry::init('User')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

working code should be

```
//let $modelName be User  
App::import("Model", "User");  
$model = new User();  
$model->find("list");
```

I hope this will help some needy fellow

Comment: The correct answer should probably be "You don't", as using a model in a helper breaks MVC. Your users list should be rather defined in your controllers and then only used by the views.

Comment: @nIcO I am very much aware about MVC but sometimes we need to display some ID or etc as relevant data to user for better understanding... this is one of those situations. Anyways thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can also load model in helper,  add following method in helper class:

Step1:

```
public function loadModel($modelClass = null, $id = null) {
    if ($modelClass === null) {
        $modelClass = $this->modelClass;
    }

    $this->uses = ($this->uses) ? (array) $this->uses : array();
    if (!in_array($modelClass, $this->uses, true)) {
        $this->uses[] = $modelClass;
    }

    list($plugin, $modelClass) = pluginSplit($modelClass, true);

    $this->{$modelClass} = ClassRegistry::init(array(
                'class' => $plugin . $modelClass, 'alias' => $modelClass, 'id' => $id
    ));
    if (!$this->{$modelClass}) {
        throw new MissingModelException($modelClass);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Step2: call above method as you do in controller like this:

```
$this->loadModel(ModelName);
```

I hope this would resolve problem

Answer (score -1):

I wanna go through helper to view data In the form of foreach

```
public function display()
{
    $links = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('category');
    $category = $links->find('all')
        ->where(['status' => 1, 'position' => 0])
        ->select([
            "category" => 'parent', 'name'
        ])
        ->toArray();
    return $category['category'];
}
```

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?